# Add custom header in CMAKE project Visual Studio

Tags: c++, docker, cmake, visual-studio-2019

I've installed a cross-compiler in a docker image.
I've deployed some custom libraries in the cross-compiler folder.
Visual Studio 2019 can compile my code, but is not able to open the custom folder.

```
#include <owa4x/pm_messages.h>
#include <owa4x/owerrors.h>
```

I've tried to add the directory in the rsync command from cmake settings, but it doesn't have any effect.

```
--include="/opt/gcc-linaro-5.3-2016.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5.3.1/include/owa4x/*"
```

Have someone an idea, please.

Comment: For example, I have the error E1696

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The header file were locate to

```
C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Linux\HeaderCache\1.0\-1280310364\opt\gcc-linaro-5.3-2016.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf\lib\gcc\arm-linux-gnueabihf\5.3.1\include
C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Linux\HeaderCache\1.0\-1280310364\opt\gcc-linaro-5.3-2016.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf\arm-linux-gnueabihf\libc\usr\include\sqlite3.h
C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Linux\HeaderCache\1.0\-1280310364\opt\gcc-linaro-5.3-2016.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf\arm-linux-gnueabihf\include
```

I've copied it in the folder

```
C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Linux\HeaderCache\1.0\-1280310364\usr\include
```